# Have executable open its own terminal window

Tags: c, macos, unix, terminal

I have an C program that currently works correctly in the terminal (open terminal window, type ./program name). I would like to package the program in such a way that it first launches its own terminal window AND THEN executes inside of this window.

[Angband](http://rephial.org/) does a rather nice job of this (at least the OSX version does). Once you launch the .app, various terminal windows open that display game information. How can I emulate this behaviour for just one terminal window?

Comment: You can do that in a linux based system invoking xterm with your program as a paremeter, for instance: xterm top

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "./YourApp"'
```

Here is simple example:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "ls -l"'
```

Comment: As far ass I can tell, Apple Script requires a full path to the program I want it to open in terminal as it will always run from the home directory and I can't guarantee a full path. Ideally, I'm looking to somehow launch a new terminal window (ideally xterm on Linux, Terminal on Mac, and Command Prompt on Windows) from within my C program.

Comment: If you don't know where your app is, and it isn't on your PATH, all bets are off in every Operating System I know!